# raspberry pi keeps killing imagemagicks convert

Tags: memory, imagemagick, raspberry-pi

My raspberry Pi keeps killing imagemagick's `convert` command when I'm resizing images, especially larger images.

Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: Have you checked the output of `dmesg`? You almost certainly don't have enough RAM and the OOM killer aborts the convert process.

Comment: yes it most certainly is an Out of Memory kill, but what can be done to mend this? Getting more memory isn't an option. Yet I refuse to believe that some jobs would be totally impossible just because of low memory.

Comment: You can create a swap partition (or a swap file) or increase the size of it if you already have one. But this will slow down the conversation significantly as well as other running applications.

Answer (score 3):

Try using ImageMagick's [resource limiting](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit) settings:
`convert -limit memory 1G ...`
This will limit memory usage to 1G when running.

To see what the current resources available, run: `convert -list resource`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out a library named epeg, which is based on libjpeg. It's proving to be *very* fast. If you're just doing simple resizes, and not using imagemagick many other features, you should consider epeg.

I posted various test results here:

- http://blog.sunekaae.com/2013/04/blazing-fast-epeg-photo-resize-on_3.html
- http://blog.sunekaae.com/2013/04/imagemagick-resize-speed-on-raspberry-pi.html